# About jQuery append() and how to check if an element has been appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I made a very simple **button click event handler**, I would like to have `<p>` element be appended when button clicked, you can check [my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/j36ye/12/):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="search_btn" value="Search" type="button">
</div>
```

```
$("#search_btn").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").append("<p id='other'>I am here</p>");
});
```

I have **two questions** to ask:

**1,** why my `.append()` does not work as I expected (that's append the `<p>` element)

**2.** in jQuery, how to check if some element is already appended? For example how to check if `<p id="other">` has already appended in my case?

**-------------------- update -------------------------------------------**

Please check [my updated code here](http://jsfiddle.net/j36ye/15/).

So, only the 2nd question remains...

Comment: jsfiddle defaults to loading MooTools.  I often forget to change it, too.

Comment: Self closing tags do not handle append function. Although you can do it with .next()

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. You are using mootools and not jQuery.
2. To check if your element exists

`if($('#other').length > 0)`

So if you do not want to append the element twice:

```
$("#search_btn").click(function() {
    if($('#other').length == 0) {
        $("#wrapper").append("<p id='other'>I am here</p>");
    }
});
```

Or, you can use the `.one(function)`[[doc](http://api.jquery.com/one/)]:

```
$("#search_btn").one('click', function() {
    $("#wrapper").append("<p id='other'>I am here</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1) jsFiddle loads in MooTools by default, you need to include jQuery for this to work. There is not a reason in the world why that example wouldn't work. (Assuming that the `$` is actually mapped to the `jQuery` object, that is.)

2) You can check the `nextSibling` of a `DOMElement`, or use the `next()` jQuery method, like so:

```
if(!$('#something').next().length) {
   //no next sibling.
}
```

Comment: Clarification on 1: the fiddle is not loading the jQuery library, but the mootools one. This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/j36ye/16/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/j36ye/17/

```
$("#search_btn").click(function(){
    if(($('#other').length) == 0) {
        $("#wrapper").append("<p id='other'>I am here</p>");
    }
    return false
});
```

Or

```
var other_appended = false;

$("#search_btn").click(function(){
    if(other_appended == false) {
         $("#wrapper").append("<p id='other'>I am here</p>");
          other_appended = true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How to check if an element exists:

```
if($("p#other").length > 0) {
    // a p element with id "other" exists
}
else {
    // a p element with id "other" does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check if element is already appended:

```
alert($(this).parent().length?'appended':'not appended');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is using the moo tools framework. Change it to use the jquery framework on the left and it works. See http://jsfiddle.net/KxGsj/